# Flutter : Why does the login page appear briefly before going to home screen every time I restart my app although the user is already logged in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, render

Flutter & Firebase : Why does the login page always appear briefly before going to home screen every time I restart my app even though the user is already logged in?

I understand that my app needs sometimes to render the user from firebase. But the user is already logged anyway. So how can I proceed the home screen immediately since the user is already logged in? Is there a way to save the user data into the phone memory?

```
class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<SystemUser>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      print('In Authenicate or Login');
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      print('In HomeScreen');
      return NavigationWrapper(); // goto homescreen

    }
  }
}
```

Please have a look and give some pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save user auth state in [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), but even in that case you will need to load some data before navigate to auth screen or home screen.

I recommend you use the following solution. This way you load auth state and then navigate the corresponding pages according to the auth state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: Provider.of<SystemUser>(context).isAuthenticate(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // while loading data
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        // if has error
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        // retrieve data - check for authentication

        // authenticated, go to homescreen
        if (snapshot.data == true) {
          print('In HomeScreen');
          return NavigationWrapper();
        }
        // not authenticated, go to auth screen
        print('In Authenicate or Login');
        return Authenticate();
      },
    );
  }
}

// in SystemUser provider

// check for auth state and return corresponding value
Future<bool> isAuthenticate() async {
  // you can implement shared prefereces
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('authKey') ?? false;
}

// whenever you logged in the user just call
prefs.setString('authKey', true);
```

Comment: What do u mean by putting those codes into SystemUser Provider?

Comment: You need to have 'isAuthenticate' method inside SystemUser  class

Comment: `The method 'isAuthenticate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isAuthenticate()`

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest You to do is to use StreamBuilder to check if the user is logged in or not like this:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator());
        else if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null)
          return LoginPage();
        else if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
        return HomePage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I use it like this in every project that needs FirebaseAuth, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using the `Consumer` element.

[image: if statement regarding authentication]

Install the `Provider` package for flutter and make a bool `isAuth`. When the user logs in, set `isAuth = true`, then add an if statement inside `home:` like in the image I provided. Hopefully that will solve your problem.